# PCB manufacturing process: covering holes with soldermask

Tags: pcb, altium, pcb-fabrication

The PCB manufacturer is asking

> These highlighted green areas (they are openings on the bottom soldermask layer) will be exposed in the bottom layer and you required us to cover the bottom layer with solder resist in the notes.
> We suggest to delete these openings of the bottom soldermask layer and cover with solder resist as your requirement.

[image]

Are they talking about deleting the holes and covering with solder mask?

- The red is the bottom layer
- The green is the bottom solder mask layer

Comment: What did you write in the notes about the solder resist?

Comment: (AFAIK solder resist and soldermask are two names for the same thing)

Comment: I didn't create anything nor design it. However, I reviewed the parameters when the design was sent for manufacturing, and there was no specific mention of solder resist. I also thought solder resist and solder mask is the same thing.

Comment: @S_D Is the designer of the PCB not available?

Comment: Is this an existing design that you're modifying or moving to a new manufacturer? Do you have a sample of the physical board that was made previously? (It sounds to me like you have a note saying that there should be soldermask as opposed to a bare copper board, and the manufacturer is mis-interpreting it to mean that there should be an unbroken soldermask layer with no openings, but this is a guess based on limited information)

Comment: It sounds like the manufacturer got a note saying that the bottom should be totally covered in solder resist, but they also got a gerber file saying where to not put the solder resist (that's the green dots), so they're confused about what you want. Do you *want* there to be solder resist everywhere except the green dots? (Usually you do, but hey, it's your board not mine)

Comment: @user253751 I think you might be right, it is possible that the issue is related to the selected via tenting option that was selected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Covering small vias with soldermask is also known as ***tenting***. In Altium, there is an option to specify whether you want tenting on the top or bottom of vias in the Solder Mask Expansion section of the via properties panel:

[image: Altium via properties panel]

I recently reinstalled Altium so I can attest to the Tenting option being turned off by default for at least vias added through the via stitching option.

Consult your fabricator for what the minimum size is that will accommodate tenting without causing manufacturing issues or voids.

Comment: I can see the option "via tented" was selected during the fabrication process hence the confusion maybe? Though on the attached picture their arrows are not all pointing towards the a via.

Comment: @S_D yeah that's another possibility: maybe you selected to tent vias but then your gerber files show no soldermask over the vias. Either way there seems to be a simple communication issue that could be solved by just talking to the manufacturer to make sure so they understand what you want.